# Java+Database - Adicionar Role a usuário já existente, através do Java

Tags: java, mongodb

Uso MongoDB com Java e preciso, através do Java executar o seguinte comando no mongoDB:

```
db.grantRolesToUser( "joao", [ {role:"dbOwner",db:"loja"} ] )
```

Ou seja, preciso adicionar uma role à um usuário já existente, e preciso especificar qual é a database. Depois de muito quebrar a cabeça, ainda não consegui achar a maneira certa. Lembrando que no comando preciso especificar qual é a database (como acima), pois nesse momento estarei logado na base admin, assim preciso dizer que o comando se refere à database loja.
Continuo procurando. Mas se alguém souber e puder me dar uma pista, agradeço!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Achei a resposta:

```
MongoClient client = new MongoClient(new MongoClientURI("mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017"));

MongoDatabase adminDatabase = client.getDatabase("admin");

adminDatabase.runCommand(new Document("grantRolesToUser", "paulo")
.append("roles", Collections.singletonList(new Document("role", "dbOwner").append("db", "loja"))));

adminDatabase.runCommand(new Document("grantRolesToUser", "paulo")
.append("roles", Collections.singletonList(new Document("role", "dbOwner").append("db", "comercio"))));

client.close();
```